# PHP wrapper that is API-compatible with PDFlib

Tags: php, api, pdflib

Are there any wrappers to any of the other PDF generating packages for PHP that provide API compatibility with PDFlib?

Our company has been generating PDFs from PHP using PDFlib for many years, but have not upgraded since version 5. Now that we are upgrading some servers, we need either upgrade or find a replacement. I'd like to replace PDFlib with an open-source product that allows commercial use. However, we (foolishly, perhaps) didn't write our own wrapper around PDFlib the first time around, and have many, many lines of code that would need to be changed and tested.

I realize I could write my own wrapper, but I find it surprising that my searching thus far has yielded no-one else who has done the same.

Comment: So I started work on my own, using the TCPDF (http://tcpdf.org) library. Since we use little of the total functionality of PDFlib, I was able to complete about 60% of a wrapper in 4 hours or so. Good enough that we probably won't be upgrading PDFlib after all.

Still be interested if anyone has a fully-featured wrapper, though.

Comment: Any intention to open source the wrapper you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one is interested, I did open-source the wrapper I wrote. It's very minimal—just enough for our needs—but it works. See [its Github page](http://github.com/IconCMO/IconPDF) for more info.

Comment: Take care, the license of the TCPDF library (which you extend with your software and which still is a PDF library) is licensed under the  GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE. You should put your code under the same license.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this PHP Class](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en) can help you out

Comment: Thanks, but, from what I've read, TCPDF has superceded that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [fpdf](http://fpdf.org) - very powerful and has lots of user generated scripts to do anything you can think of.

Also free